# Why Qt c files just have header inclusion and no implementaion code?

Tags: qt

I wanted to look into the implementation of QString. But when I opened the QString.c file then all I can see was header inclusion of qstring.h. So where is the actual implementation?

Comment: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/text/qstring.cpp https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/text/qstring.h

Comment: There is also a very useful and nice looking website with some IDE-like functionality: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstring.cpp.html

Answer (score 0):

Qt creates a bunch of include files like the one you mention, its only purpose is to let the developer include using that syntax sugar, ie:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>
```

The 'real' header files are in another 'reachable' directory in the form you metion (qstring.h), so you can also do this:

```
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qobject.h>
```

So the first kind includes the second one. The actual directory depends on your distribution/installation, in my case the second ones ('real' content) are at '/usr/include/Qt'.

Of course this is only the header file where all declarations are, if you mean by implementation the definition of the content, that will be somewhere in the source code (in .cpp files), and it's location depends on the particular module.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the implementation. An example would suffice.

Comment: @eyllanesc already pointed out a location for the implementation, but you are somehow misleading using that word. Because implementation usually address the definitions of the declarations, they are usually in cpp files. If what you are really asking for is the header file with all its content, I already pointed it you, all is in /usr/include/Qt (at least in my distro). ie: /usr/include/Qt/qstring.h